# How can i send this type of structure in retrofit android?

Tags: android, json, gson, image-uploading, retrofit

How can i send this type of structure in retrofit android with @Multipart annotation?In my requestFields array i can add multipart images or Typedstring value.

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/adduserrequestservice")
    void addUserRequestService(@Part("checksum") TypedString checksum, @Part("userId") TypedString userId,
                               @Part("reqType") TypedString requesttype,@Part("reqFormType") TypedString reqFormtype,
                               @Part("requestFields") List<RequestFields> requestFields,
                               @Part("timestamp") Long timestamp,retrofit.Callback<RetrieveResponse> callback);




    { 
            "checksum"      : "747d23f4333f05c60d57f83ab3648e2e",
            "userId"        : 1,
            "reqType"       : "Medical Devices",
            "reqFormType"   : "General Request",
            "requestFields"  : [
                                    {
                                        "fieldName" : "xxx",
                                        "fieldValue" : "s3343"
                                    }
                                ],
            "timestamp" : 1403477427
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object like this:

```
class Body2Send {
     public String checksum;
     public int userId;
     public String reqType;
     public String reqFormType;
     public List<KVObject> requiredFields;
     public long timestamp;
}

public KVObject {
    String fieldName;
    String fieldValue;
}
```

and send it within the request body:

```
public interface MyRetrofitService {
    @POST("some/path")
    Result request(@Body Body2Send item);
}
```

Your Images must be Base64 Encoded then, of course

Comment: Thanks... but I have done this but the main problem is that how can i send this object with @Multipart annotation as i have to add support for images as well in my requestFields[] array ..

Comment: Either you send it as a multipart request (valid json block - image) or base64 encoded.

In theory you could mix that up (invalid json, image, invalid json) but this is bad approach and does not work with retrofit.

may be I understand that wrong, could you add an image example in your request snippet?

Comment: "requestFields"  : [
                                {
                                    "fieldName" : "xxx",
                                    "fieldValue" : "SomeImageurl"
                                }
                            ]